# Cypress: How to verify generated checkBox is checked and has attribute aria-checked="true"

Tags: html, checkbox, attributes, cypress, checked

I want to verify that a checkbox is checked. But it isn't a usually checkbox from type="checkbox", so it HASN'T the property "checked".
Instead of this you can find in the HTML-Doom  aria-checked="true".
How can I read out this value?

HTML-Snipet:

```
<mat-checkbox class="mat-checkbox mat-primary mat-checkbox-checked" aria-label="checkBoxCapacityBaseEditDayofWeek: 1" id="DAY1">
  <label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="DAY1-input">
  <span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">
   <input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="DAY1-input" tabindex="0" value="1" aria-checked="true">
```

What I've tried for so long:

Cypress-Code (nothing works):

```
// cy.get('#DAY2')
    // .should('have.value', 'aria-checked="true"')
    
    cy.get('#DAY1')
    .should('have.attr', 'aria-checked', 'false')

    cy.get('#DAY2')
    .should('have.attr', 'aria-checked', 'true')

    // .invoke('val', 'aria-checked')
    // .should('eq', true)
    // .should('have.prop', 'aria-checked', true)
    // .should('have.attr', 'aria-checked', 'true')
```

How can I get to the value  true?

EDIT:
I found the solution:
Cypress-Code:

```
cy.get('#DAY1-input').should('have.attr', 'aria-checked', 'true')
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with what you're trying is that you're only selecting the parent element with your `cy.get()`. If you use `.find()` you can chain off of the parent element to find child elements. Something like the following should work:

```
cy.get('#DAY1')
  .find('#DAY1-input')
  .should('have.attr', 'aria-checked', true);
```

Additionally, you could just select the `DAY1-input` element directly, since it has a unique identifier:

```
cy.get('#DAY1-input')
  .should('have.attr', 'aria-checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I already found it by myself... I must have overseen tee explicit identifier all the time... shame on me^^

Comment: Haha whoops! I hadn't seen your edit when I posted. Glad you were able to figure this out :D

Comment: Note: I had to use "true" as a string not a boolean true for this to work for me as of today. (Cypress v12.12.0)

Answer (score 0):

`.should('have.prop', 'checked', true);`
I think it's going to help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).